# jQuery "crop" div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I hope I'm not repeating - it doesn't seem like there are any questions that have the same specifications as mine.

I'm looking for a way to "crop" a div with jQuery. The div is going to start with a width of zero, and then get animated to its full length. The tricky part is I want any text that overflows on the side to be hidden, rather than just pushed down to fill the space.

It doesn't seem like the regular "overflow: hidden" will work because I could have many lines of text, and I want each line to be "cropped", so the characters for the individual line are hidden instead of being bumped down to the next line. [image: "cropped div"]

I hope this is clear. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use nested elements and CSS:

```
<div id="content">
   <p>Paragraph 1</p>
   <p>Paragraph 2</p>
   <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

In CSS you'll want to set the `p` elements's width to the full amount and set overflow to wrap.  You'll then want the `div` element to have overflow hidden and animate that element's width.

```
p { width: 300px; margin-top: 18px; }
#content { overflow: hidden; width: 50px; }
```

If you won't want the extra div in your markup you can create the wrapper div in jQuery and put the paragraphs inside it when it comes time to animate.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XsLAT/

Comment: @Zak, here's an example how this would look like (only CSS no jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/YeG7v/1/

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/Zeg3z/4/

The `#wrapper` div will control the cropping with `overflow-x: hidden`; it won't display content outside of its width. The `#text` div will contain the actual text and if you specify a width for this container, then the lines will not change as the `#wrapper` div expands.

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the `white-space` CSS property with the `nowrap` option.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/532H8/

Adjust the width to see more or less of the text.